# How can i apply Local Storage to my todolist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am doing some practice javascript/jquery exercise. My project look like 'trello' but much soft and simple.

When i writing some list/plan to input, javscript adding dynamically 'card' but if 
i refresh the page/chrome, all things gone or lost.

So i wanna apply localstorage on my project. Thanks for all helps...

Here is my [todolist](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/RBgeRR).

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours();
  var m = date.getMinutes();
  var s = date.getSeconds();

  if (h < 10) {
    h = "0" + h;
  }

  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }

  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }

  var time = h + ":" + m + "." + s;
  document.getElementById('hours').innerText = time;
  document.getElementById('hours').textContent = time;
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000)

let generateComment = comment => ` <div class="comment"><h5>${comment}</h5></div> `

$('#button').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var comment = $('#button').val()
    $(this).val('');
    var text = $(generateComment(comment));
  }

  $('.yorum').append(text)
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* make main axis vertical */
  justify-content: center;
  /* center items vertically, in this case */
  align-items: center;
  /* center items horizontally, in this case */
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #69034c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #b9f6ca;
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(24, 1, 1, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #020701;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 6px solid #556677;
}

.yorum {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.comment {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5ba;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1 id="hours"></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <input type="text" id="button"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="yorum"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you would need to store an array in localStorage which you can `push()` to when needed. As localStorage can only contain strings you'll need to serialise/deserialise the data you retrieve from it before accessing and saving. To do that you can use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

Once the data is stored you'll simply need to add some logic which checks localStorage when the page loads then displays all the items in the array in the UI, something like this:

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
  var m = ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var s = ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

  var time = h + ":" + m + "." + s;
  $('#hours').text(time);
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000)

$('#button').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $('#button').val();    
    var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
    store.push(comment);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(store));

    $(this).val('');
    displayComment(comment);
  }
});

function displayComment(comment) {
  var html = $(`<div class="comment"><h5>${comment}</h5></div>`);
  $('.yorum').append(html);
}

var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
store.forEach(displayComment);
```

[**Updated Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBgeeV)

Note that I also included some other optimisations to your logic to make it more succinct, such as using jQuery DOM selectors and also using `slice()` to force the time values to have leading zeroes.

Comment: You are the best man! LocalStroge really difficult to understand for me. Thanks for effort. :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Save Card data:

```
localStorage.setItem("cardID", yourCardData);
```

Delete Card data:

```
localStorage.removeItem("cardID");
```

Get an saved card data:

```
var Card = localStorage.getItem("CardID");
```

But if you want to store an array of data cards i think the solution may be:

```
var cards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cards")) || []
```

When var cards is changed use:

```
localStorage.setItem("cards", JSON.stringify(cards));
```

You can read more information about localStorage here: [Window localStorage Property - w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("cards" || "[]")` won't work as you're expecting it to. See my answer for the correct syntax

Comment: Also please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan . Edited: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cards")) || []`